# Search for an exact phrase and change

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with changing values ​​into a string.
I have three values, e.g. a, aa, aaa

```c#
StringBuilder builders = new StringBuilder(string);
builders.Replace("a", "ab");
builders.Replace("aa", "bab");
builders.Replace("aaa", "bba");
string new_string = builders.ToString();
```

How to do it to find exactly the value of 'aaa' because for this value both the condition of 'a' and 'aa' is also fulfilled.

Comment: Since you are using a procedural / object oriented language the order of your statements determines the order of execution. So "a" is replaced first, and if the "a" was part of an "aa" it no longer is after that, because it's "aba" now.

Comment: Since 'bba' contains 'a' should it be ultimately converted to 'bbab'? If *not*, you'll have to replace with temporary tokens and then replace those at the very end. If `StringBuilder` is not a requirement and you aren't concerned with performance, you may try switching to `Regex.Replace(string, string, MatchEvaluator)` using an alternation with longest substrings first or a greedy quantifier

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to replace the long tokens first.

It looks like your replacement strings also contain "a". So you might need to replace them with a temporary string (one that is unlikely to occur in the original text), and then convert to the target string after you've processed them all.

The only way to intelligently only replace "a" without replacing "aa" is to parse each character in the text to determine how long each token is. It's not that hard, but a lot more work than calling `Replace()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the replaces from the longest substring to the shortest one:

```
builders.Replace("aaa", "bba");
builders.Replace("aa", "bab");
builders.Replace("a", "ab");
```

Comment: Using this code, "aaa" will be converted to "bba", and then be converted to "bbab". Are you sure that's what the OP wanted?